# Showing identity map between $(C,|\cdot|)$ and $(C,\|\cdot\|)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $C$ denote the vector space of continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Endow the space with the norms $|f|=\sup\{|f(x)|:x\in [0,1]\}$ or the $L^1$, $\|f\|=\int^1_0|f(x)|\,dx$.
Now show that the identity map $id:(C,|\cdot|)\to(C,\|\cdot\|)$ is continuous.

It seems like , I can just say: Let $\epsilon>0,f,g \in C$ and pick $\delta=\epsilon,$ then when $|f-g|<\delta$ we have $\|id(f)-id(g)\|=\int^1_0|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx\leq\int^1_0\epsilon\,dx=\epsilon$ and hence $id$ is continuous. But it is just awfully short and I am not sure if I missed anything.

Comment: It is correct. It is because the $\sup$ norm is much 'stronger' than the $L^1$ norm.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! For the inverse identity map on those vector spaces, if I want to show that $id^{-1}$, it seems like I can just pick $\epsilon =|f(x_0)-g(x_0)|$ for some fixed $x_0\in [0,1]$ then for all $\delta >0$ we will always have $|f-g|\geq \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is just awfully short

It's correct and, actually, it's too long. You have (using $|f|$ to denote absolute value and $\|f\|_\infty$ to denote the sup norm)
$$
\|f\|_1=\int_0^1|f|\leq\int_0^1\|f\|_\infty=\|f\|_\infty, 
$$
which shows that the identity map is bounded and hence continuous.

Answer (score 1):

As noted it is correct.

Another way of putting it,  the topology $\tau_{\text{sup}}$ induced by the sup norm is *finer* than that, $\tau_{L^1}$, induced by the $L^1$ norm.  That's $\tau_{L^1}\subset \tau_{\text {sup}}$.

Thus under the identity function,  and those two norms, the inverse image of every open set is open.

Of course the slicker way is given in the other answer:  since you have a normed vector space,  you can just check that the identity map is bounded (which is true if it's bounded on the unit ball).  I think you need linearity (sorry my functional analysis is very rusty).